# Why do I get [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] when I try to use my custom login form with NextAuth?

Tags: typescript, next-auth, next.js13, react-server-components

I'm trying to create a custom login page with next-auth, I created my file and call the signIn function but I end up having a error message `[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR], https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Failed to fetch {error: {…}, url: '/api/auth/csrf', message: 'Failed to fetch'`. I add the `NEXTAUTH_URL` as indicated in the doc but it did not solve the error and I can't sign in with my form.

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.4.0",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.0.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.5",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  }
}
```

api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        console.log("credentials", credentials);
        const user = { id: "1", name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" };
        console.log("user", user);
        if (user) return user;
        else return null;
      }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signIn",
  },
  debug: true,
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

auth/signIn

```
'use client';
import React from "react";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

import styles from "./page.module.scss";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default function LoginPage() {
const userNameRef = React.useRef\<HTMLInputElement\>(null);
const passwordRef = React.useRef\<HTMLInputElement\>(null);
const session = useSession();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (session.status === "authenticated") redirect("/admin");
    }, [session]);
    
    const onSubmit = async () => {
        const result = signIn("Credentials", { username: "jsmith", password: "1234" })
        console.log("value", result);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.login}>
            <form className={styles.login__form}>
                <h1 className={styles.login__form__title}>Login</h1>
                <div className={styles.login__form__label__input}>
                    <label className={styles.login__form__label}>Username</label>
                    <input ref={userNameRef} className={styles.login__form__input} type="text"></input>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.login__form__label__input}>
                    <label className={styles.login__form__label}>Password</label>
                    <input 
                        ref={passwordRef} 
                        className={styles.login__form__input} type="password">
                    </input>
                </div>
                <button onClick={onSubmit} className={styles.login__form__button}>Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );

}
```

.env

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET="784923748923748972938478fioswhjifuhef409283094823"
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

I tried the default sign-in form from next-auth and it was working perfectly but when i tried to use my form it did not work, I tried to look in the doc if i forgot to add something in the `NextAuthOptions` but I don't see what.